# GitHub GraphQL API Filter only ACTIONS for packageManager

Tags: github, graphql, github-api

I have a GraphQL query as below where I want to get only the ACTIONS package manager. I could not find a way to filter this through GitHub docs.

How I easily achieve this without looping over 250 packages?

```
query {
  repository(owner: "$organization", name:"$repository"){
    url
    name
    dependencyGraphManifests{
      nodes{
          dependencies {
                totalCount
                nodes{
                    packageName
                    requirements
                    hasDependencies
                    packageManager
                }
          }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```
{
    "data": {
        "repository": {
            "url": "https://github.com/<organization>/<repository>",
            "name": "sp-integration-docs",
            "dependencyGraphManifests": {
                "nodes": [
                    {
                        "dependencies": {
                            "totalCount": 250,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "packageName": "@algolia/autocomplete-core",
                                    "requirements": "= 1.9.3",
                                    "hasDependencies": true,
                                    "packageManager": "NPM"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "@algolia/autocomplete-plugin-algolia-insights",
                                    "requirements": "= 1.9.3",
                                    "hasDependencies": true,
                                    "packageManager": "NPM"
                                }, 
                               ...
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "dependencies": {
                            "totalCount": 3,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "packageName": "actions/checkout",
                                    "requirements": "= 4",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "actions/setup-node",
                                    "requirements": "= 4",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "peaceiris/actions-gh-pages",
                                    "requirements": "= 4a2e02b36f31d8974a0d09d3bb9f3172aa2d0d0d",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "dependencies": {
                            "totalCount": 3,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "packageName": "actions/checkout",
                                    "requirements": "= 2",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "peter-evans/create-pull-request",
                                    "requirements": "= 153407881ec5c347639a548ade7d8ad1d6740e38",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "tibdex/github-app-token",
                                    "requirements": "= b62528385c34dbc9f38e5f4225ac829252d1ea92",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "dependencies": {
                            "totalCount": 2,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "packageName": "peter-evans/create-or-update-comment",
                                    "requirements": "= 5f728c3dae25f329afbe34ee4d08eef25569d79f",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "organization/jira-issue-action",
                                    "requirements": "= ae96b6d17fe107826d13ec31e3faf65ff1a60c82",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "dependencies": {
                            "totalCount": 2,
                            "nodes": [
                                {
                                    "packageName": "actions/github-script",
                                    "requirements": "= d7906e4ad0b1822421a7e6a35d5ca353c962f410",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                },
                                {
                                    "packageName": "organization/commisery-action",
                                    "requirements": "= 2",
                                    "hasDependencies": false,
                                    "packageManager": "ACTIONS"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```